# Is the Hausdorff metric on sub-$\sigma$-fields separable?

Tags: pr.probability, fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, metric-spaces

Let $(X,\mu,\mathcal{F})$ be a probability space.  The paper *[Equiconvergence of Martingales](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoms/1177693405)* by Edward Boylan introduced a pseudometric on sub-$\sigma$-fields (sub-$\sigma$-algebras) of $\mathcal{F}$ as follows:

$\rho(\mathcal{G},\mathcal{H})
 := \sup_{A\in \mathcal{G}} \inf_{B\in \mathcal{H}} \mu(A \triangle B) + \sup_{B\in \mathcal{H}} \inf_{A\in \mathcal{G}} \mu(A \triangle B)$

where $A \triangle B$ is symmetric difference.

It seems to be called the Hausdorff pseudometric on $\sigma$-fields in later papers. (Does anyone know why?) Further, if we only consider a $\mu$-complete $\sigma$-fields then $\rho$ is a metric.  Also, the paper shows $\rho$ is complete.

> Is this metric $\rho$
>   separable---assuming, say, $X=[0,1]$
>   and $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure?

My guess is that it is not, but I cannot off-hand come up with a witnessing set to show this.  Considering the paper is 40 years old, I imagine this might be well-known.  And if it is not separable, then my follow up question is this?

> Is there a known separable, complete
>   metric on the space of
>   $\mu$-complete sub-$\sigma$-fields?

For reference, I found the following list [$20of$20sigma-fields%22%7Csort:date/sci.math/iz249jCUvEU/rkKOei1NV5YJ" rel="nofollow noreferrer">online](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/sci.math/%22Hausdorff-metric<span class=), compiled by Dave L. Renfro,  of papers dealing with metrics on $\sigma$-fields (listed in Chronological order).  I quickly looked though these papers and didn't find what I was looking for, but maybe I missed something.

1. Edward S. Boylan, "Equiconvergence of martingales",
   Annals of Mathematical Statistics 42
   (1971), 552-559.    [MR 44 #7603; Zbl 218.60049]
2. Jacques Neveu, "Note on the tightness of the metric on the
   set of complete sub sigma-algebras of a probability space",
   Annals of Mathematical Statistics 43 (1972), 1369-1371.
   [MR 48 #5133; Zbl 241.60036]
3. Hirokichi Kudo, "A note on the strong convergence of
   sigma-algebras", Annals of Probability 2 (1974), 76-83.
   [MR 51 #6900; Zbl 275.60007]
4. Lothar Rogge, "Uniform inequalities for conditional
   expectations", Annals of Probability 2 (1974), 486-489.
   [MR 50 #14858; Zbl 285.28010]
5. Louis H. Blake, "Some further results concerning
   equiconvergence of martingales", Revue Roumaine de
   Mathématiques Pures et Appliquées 28 (1983), 927-932.
   [MR 86i:60130; Zbl 524.60029]
6. Hari G. Mukerjee, "Almost sure equiconvergence of
   conditional expectations", Annals of Probability 12
   (1984), 733-741. [MR 86c:28012; Zbl 557.28001]
7. Beth Allen, "Convergence of sigma-fields and applications
   to mathematical economics", pp. 161-174 in Gerald Hammer
   and Diethard Pallaschke (editors), SELECTED TOPICS IN
   OPERATIONS RESEARCH AND MATHEMATICAL ECONOMICS (Proceedings,
   Karlsruhe, West Germany, 22-25 August 1983), Lecture Notes
   in Economics and Mathematical Systems #226, Springer-Verlag, 1984. 
   [MR 86f:90029; Zbl 547.28001]
8. Dieter Landers and Lothar Rogge, "An inequality for the
   Hausdorff-metric of sigma-fields", Annals of Probability
   14 (1986), 724-730. [MR 87h:60006; Zbl 597.60003]
9. Abdallah M. Al-Rashed, "On countable unions of sigma
   algebras", Journal of Karachi Mathematical Association
   8 (1986), 57-63. [MR 88f:28001; Zbl 639.28001]
10. Maxwell B. Stinchcombe, "A further note on Bayesian
    information topologies", Journal of Mathematical Economics
    22 (1993), 189-193. [MR 93k:60011; Zbl 773.90016]
11. Timothy Van Zandt, "The Hausdorff metric of sigma-fields
    and the value of information", Annals of Probability 21
    (1993), 161-167. [MR 94d:62012; Zbl 777.62007]
12. Xikui Wang, "Completeness of the set of sub-sigma-algebras",
    International Journal of Mathematics and Mathematical
    Sciences 16 (1993), 511-514. [MR 94f:28002; Zbl 782.28001]
13. Zvi Artstein, "Compact convergence of sigma-fields and
    relaxed conditional expectation", Probability Theory and
    Related Fields [= Zeitschrift für Wahrscheinlichkeits-
    theorie] 120 (2001), 369-394. [MR 2002g:28003; Zbl 992.28001]

Comment: It is called the *Hausdorff pseudometric* because it is an instance of Haudsorff's construction starting with pseudometric $\mu(A \triangle B)$.  In general, Hausdorff's construction starts with a pseudometric and constructs a new pseucometric on subsets of the original space.  See here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance .

Comment: As a first step, what is the cardinality of the set of complete $\sigma$-algebras?  If it isn't $2^{\aleph_0}$, then that's certainly an obstruction.

Comment: @Gerald Edgar, thanks I thought it might be something like that.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge, I think it is size continuum as follows: If $\rho(\mathcal{G},\mathcal{H})\neq 0$, then $f \mapsto E[f \mid \mathcal{G}]$ and $f \mapsto E[f \mid \mathcal{H}]$ are different operators.  But in $L^2$ these operators are continuous linear transformations of which there are only continuum many (correct?).

Comment: Maybe someone can fix this? Apparently the [substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_(logic)) doesn't hold for URL exchanges.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a sequence $A_n$ of independent sets of measure $1/2$. Given   two different subsets $B$ and $C$ of natural numbers, suppose WLOG that there is an $n$ in $B\sim C$. Now $\mu(A_n\Delta A) = 1/2$ for all sets $A$ which are independent of $A_n$, so the distance from the sigma algebra generated by $(A_n)_{n\in B}$ to the sigma algebra generated by 
$(A_n)_{n\in C}$ is at least $1/2$.  This shows that the density character of your space is at least the continuum.

Comment: Thanks!  I assume $B\sim C$ is set subtraction.  I feel a bit silly for not noticing this construction.  Also, by my comment to Nate above, the space has size continuum, so the density character is exactly the continuum.

Comment: That's right, Jason.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the following is a dense set:

For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ take all sub-algebras of the finite sigma-algebra generated by intervals of the form $[i/2^n,(i+1)/2^n)$, $i=0,\ldots,2^n-1$.

Comment: Unfortunately not.  (I had thought this at first too.)  By Bill Johnson's answer, every pair in your sequence has distance 1/2. (So this sequence doesn't even converge in this metric to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra which it generates.)  A similar example is in the original paper.  (I just didn't see at the time how to extend it to a collection of size continuum as Bill did.)

Comment: I see. I was sure wrong.